# Number theory problem with order

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p\in\mathbb{P}, a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\nmid a, ord_p a=d, k_0=\upsilon_p(a^d-1)$($\upsilon_p(a)=k$ denotes $p^k\mid a, p^{k+1}\nmid a$). Then prove that if $k\geq k_0$, then $ord_{p^k}(a)=dp^{k-k_0}$

Since $k_0=\upsilon_p(a^d-1)\implies p^{k_0}\mid\mid a^d-1$ and $a^{dp^{k-k_0}}-1=(a^d-1)(a^{d(p^{k-k_0}-1)}+...+a^d+1)$. Then it's sufficient to prove that $p^{k-k_0}\mid a^{d(p^{k-k_0}-1)}+...+a^d+1$(it should be true). But it's only $a^d\equiv1(mod p^{k_0})$ so $a^{d(p^{k-k_0}-1)}+...+a^d+1\equiv p^{k-k_0}(modp^k)$. but I want to prove $a^{d(p^{k-k_0}-1)}+...+a^d+1\equiv p^{k-k_0}\equiv 0(modp^{k-k_0})$. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Have $p \not\mid q$ with

$$a^d - 1 = p^{k_{0}}q \implies a^d = p^{k_{0}}q + 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

For simpler algebra, let

$$n = p^{k-k_{0}} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) expansion to get

$$(a^d)^{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(p^{k_{0}}q)^{n-i}(1)^{i} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Show $p^k$ divides each term on the right side of \eqref{eq3A} except for the final $1$ term. Also, confirm no smaller power than $n$, i.e., $p^{k-k_{0}}$, will work in \eqref{eq3A} to then determine that

$$\operatorname{ord}_{p^{k}}(a) = dp^{k-k_0} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$